# How can I show hide my logout button based on authentication without using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

With the code below, the logout button will only show if I refresh the page upon being successfully being logged in.  The functionality works as intended, so no issues there.

Furthermore, I'd like to show the logout button on the navbar upon the user successfully logging in *without* refreshing page.

I've tried many ways to solve this but to no avail.

During my research, I came across something called Redux Persist but I'm unsure if it's worth using it in this scenario.  Is there a way I can handle this without using Redux?

I'm open to code improvements/suggestions of my code.  Thanks in advance.

```
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const NavBar = () => {

    let history = useHistory();
    const [loggedInUser, setLoggedInUser] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("loginToken");
        console.log(loggedInUser);
        setLoggedInUser(loggedInUser);
    });

    const logout = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const headers = {
            "Accept" : "application/json",
            "Authorization" : `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('loginToken')}`
        };
    
        axios.post('http://website.test/api/logout', null, {headers})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                if(res.status === 200) {
                    localStorage.clear();
                    return history.push('/');
                }
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
                    { loggedInUser ? <Nav className="me-auto"><Button onClick={logout}>Logout</Button></Nav> : null }
                </Container>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: I think you're login logic is in another component? So the State from there has to be passed to this "Navigation"-Component. You need the state in a higher component and have to pass it to the navigation component. Or use React Context for a "global" state handling.

Comment: @Pukka When I login, `console.log(loggedInUser);` displays nothing in the console.  It's only when I refresh the login token appears not once, but twice.  It looks like when I refresh the page, the `useEffect()` is being executed twice - interesting behavior.

Comment: Your useEffect is running twice because you haven't added any dependency array. It runs once when the component is rendered and once after the state change . If you want it to run only once add the dependency array as `[]` your useEffect should be like this `useEffect(() => { .... }, []);`

Comment: @Shyam Wow very cool... thanks for sharing that knowledge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React gets not "notified" if the local storage has changed. React only reacts on state (useState, context, redux, ...) changes. The simplest way is something like this:

--App.jsx

```js
const App = () => {
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState(localStorage.getItem("loginToken"));

  return (
   <>
     <Navigation userState={userState} setUserState={setUserState} />
     {!userState && <Login setUserState={setUserState} />}
   </>
  )
}
```

--Login.jsx

```js
const Login = ({ setUserState }) => {
  const onLoginButtonClick = () => {
    //.. do api request
    setUserState('myState')
  }
  return (
    <button onClick={onButtonClick} />
  )
}
```

--Navigation.jsx

```js
const Navigation = ({ userState, setUserState }) => {
 const onLogoutButtonClick => {
  //..do api request
  localStorage.setItem('loginToken', null);
  setUserState(null);

 }
 return (
  <>
   <div>some things</div>
   { userState && <button onClick={onLogoutButtonClick}>logout</button> }
  </>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, i don't like Redux (maybe like you), i use React Tracked (https://github.com/dai-shi/react-tracked), it has some functions like Redux but quite simple to use.

Secondly, you should call API query via dispatch, it is easy to read and write your logic code.

Like Redux, React Tracked use Center State but only reload component if need, not all component reload at the same time.

And my answer: without refreshing page and don't use Redux, use React Tracked!

Note: `useEffect()` should call with empty dependencies like this: `useEffect(()=> {}, [])`

Before `localStorage.clear();` you must add `setLoggedInUser(false);` and if you place `return history.push('/');` here, your page will be reloaded!